# Strategy vs Delegates

Tags: java, design-patterns, strategy, delegates

Can the `Strategy` design pattern entirely replace `delegates`?

In `Java`, for example, there are no delegates. Is it possible to gain all the features of `delegates` by using `Strategy` design pattern?

**Edit**: I see there is some ambiguity in my question. By `delegates` I mean the feature of the language, C# for instance.

Comment: _in Java there are no delegates_ - in that sense one can say, there is no Strategy either. There's nothing to "overcome"

Comment: @gnat, design patters cannot be or not be in a language. The question is whether all the features provided by delegates can be gained by using such design pattern.

Comment: are you asking about [delegate pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_pattern "what's this?") or about C# language feature?

Comment: @gnat, its about the language feature, C# and some others have it.

Comment: when the feature is used to support the pattern it named after, why would one use _other_ pattern in Java for stuff that needs this kind design? why not just implement Delegate pattern when one needs it? Just search web for something like _delegation pattern in JDK API_ to see how it can be done

Comment: @gnat, this is not quite the same. In delegation pattern one object calls methods from somewhere else to 'help' it. Strategy pattern defines some algorithms, encapsulates them and makes them interchagable. So the object can dynamically decide which algorithm/method to use. In the delegation pattern, there is no such dynamic choice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to gain all the features of delegates by using Strategy design pattern?

Not exactly.

In C#, delegates are used to implement the strategy pattern nicely and easily. Sometimes, virtual dispatch via inheritance is used to implement the strategy pattern because it fits better for the problem. Rarely, overloaded dynamic methods are used.

Java really only has the second as an option at the moment.

It's not really correct to say that the strategy pattern can provide delegate behavior because one is a design pattern and the other is a construct. The whole Turing completeness thing says that Java **can** emulate delegate behavior, but a number of the delegate's features (capturing local variables, multi-casting) will fall outside of what a Strategy pattern solves.

Answer (score 12):

A delegate is a just a class with no data and one method.  This is easy to implement in almost any OO language, including even C#, and certainly Java.

C# (using a delegate):

```
public delegate bool Test( int, int );
// And in some other class/method:
    SortEm.sort( ilist, (a, b) => a < b );
// And in static class SortEm:
public static void sort( int[] list, Test test )  {
    ...
    if (test( x, y ))  {
    ...
}
```

Java:

```
public interface JDelegate  {
    public boolean test( int a, int b );
}
// And in some other class/method:
    SortEm.sort( ilist,
        // Anonymous Class
        new JDelegate()  {
            @Override public boolean test( int a, int b )  { return a < b; }
        }
    );
// And in class SortEm:
public static void sort( int[] list, JDelegate sorter )  {
    ...
    if (sorter.test( x, y ))  {
    ...
}
```

The Java needs a bit more typing.  It does use existing concepts rather than creating new ones (*delegate*, for instance), which makes it easier if you're coming back to Java after spending a year on C.  Also, the "JDelegate" interface can become a lot more elaborate if needed, as can the class actually passed, which could be a named (rather than anonymous) class implementing JDelegate.

The big C# edge in this is that the most commonly used section in this code is the call to sort--one line versus four, in this case.  But the functionality is there in Java and probably any OO language.

Doing this in C# *without* delegates is left as an exercise for the reader.